# Problems with theano when trying to use pymc3

Tags: python, conda, pymc3

I have been trying to use the pymc3 package but have constantly been receiving errors. First off, when I import the pymc3 package, here is what happens:

```
import pymc3 as pm
```

> WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
> WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.

Afterwards, here is my code:

```
x = np.linspace(-5,5, 50)  # Wavelength data. Here we have fifty points between -5 and 5
sigma = 1
mu = 0
A = 20
B = 100
# define underlying model -- Gaussian
y = A * np.exp( - (x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)) + B
y_noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, 50)  # Let's add some noise
data = y+y_noise
# Set model
basic_model = pm.Model()
with basic_model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    A = pm.Uniform("A", lower=0, upper=50)
    B = pm.Uniform("B", lower=0, upper=200)
    sigma = 1
    # Expected value of outcome
    y_m = A*np.exp(-(x)**2/2)+B
# Likelihood  of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=np.sqrt(data), observed=data)
# Now sample
with basic_model:
    # draw posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample_smc(100, parallel=True)
```

And here is the error output:

> RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call
> last) RemoteTraceback:  """ Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py",
> line 125, in worker
> result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py",
> line 51, in starmapstar
> return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymc3/smc/sample_smc.py",
> line 267, in sample_smc_int
> smc.setup_kernel()   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymc3/smc/smc.py",
> line 135, in setup_kernel
> self.likelihood_logp_func = logp_forw([self.model.datalogpt], self.variables, shared)   File
> "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymc3/smc/smc.py",
> line 288, in logp_forw
> f = theano_function([inarray0], out_list[0])   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/compile/function/**init**.py",
> line 337, in function
> fn = pfunc(   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/compile/function/pfunc.py",
> line 524, in pfunc
> return orig_function(   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/compile/function/types.py",
> line 1970, in orig_function
> m = Maker(   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/compile/function/types.py",
> line 1573, in **init**
> self._check_unused_inputs(inputs, outputs, on_unused_input)   File "/home/osgrinds/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/theano/compile/function/types.py",
> line 1745, in _check_unused_inputs
> raise UnusedInputError(msg % (inputs.index(i), i.variable, err_msg)) theano.compile.function.types.UnusedInputError:
> theano.function was asked to create a function computing outputs given
> certain inputs, but the provided input variable at index 0 is not part
> of the computational graph needed to compute the outputs: inarray. To
> make this error into a warning, you can pass the parameter
> on_unused_input='warn' to theano.function. To disable it completely,
> use on_unused_input='ignore'. """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> UnusedInputError                          Traceback (most recent call
> last) Input In [7], in <cell line: 2>()
> 1 # Now sample
> 2 with basic_model:
> 3     # draw posterior samples
> ----> 4     trace = pm.sample_smc(100, parallel=True)
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pymc3/smc/sample_smc.py:196,
> in sample_smc(draws, kernel, n_steps, start, tune_steps, p_acc_rate,
> threshold, save_sim_data, save_log_pseudolikelihood, model,
> random_seed, parallel, chains, cores)
> 194 loggers = [_log] + [None] * (chains - 1)
> 195 pool = mp.Pool(cores)
> --> 196 results = pool.starmap(
> 197     sample_smc_int, [(*params, random_seed[i], i, loggers[i]) for i in range(chains)]
> 198 )
> 200 pool.close()
> 201 pool.join()
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py:372,
> in Pool.starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
> 366 def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
> 367     '''
> 368     Like `map()` method but the elements of the `iterable` are expected to
> 369     be iterables as well and will be unpacked as arguments. Hence
> 370     `func` and (a, b) becomes func(a, b).
> 371     '''
> --> 372     return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
>
> File
> ~/anaconda3/envs/pymc3Env/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/pool.py:771,
> in ApplyResult.get(self, timeout)
> 769     return self._value
> 770 else:
> --> 771     raise self._value
>
> UnusedInputError: theano.function was asked to create a function
> computing outputs given certain inputs, but the provided input
> variable at index 0 is not part of the computational graph needed to
> compute the outputs: inarray. To make this error into a warning, you
> can pass the parameter on_unused_input='warn' to theano.function. To
> disable it completely, use on_unused_input='ignore'.

I am simply following a tutorial on medium, so I don't think there is a problem with the code. I have a strong feeling that the problems arises from the way I installed the packages. I installed pymc3 in a conda environment by using these 3 commands:

```
conda install numpy scipy mkl
conda install theano pygpu
conda install pymc3
```

I have also tried installing pymc3 by following the guide from the developpers on github:

```
conda create -c conda-forge -n pymc3_env pymc3 theano-pymc mkl mkl-service
conda activate pymc3_env
```

Comment: try with `conda install mingw`

Comment: @Seintian I received this error: PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

Comment: mh this: `conda install -c conda-forge mingwpy`? so it will search also in its `forge` database

Comment: [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/mingwpy) is the guide to install it, if that does not work

Comment: @Seintian Sadly none of the 3 options worked, I am quite confused. It seems as if it is not available on any of the channels.

Comment: it's very strange... did you try using `pip`?

Comment: @Seintian why are you assuming this is Windows? All of your suggestions are Windows-specific and not even clear why they would help in this situation.

Comment: actually I'm not assuming that @merv . `pip` is available in Windows, MacOS and Linux, too. Those suggestions are from official guides and tutorials I searched for on Google, since I have never had a similar error. I advised them because he was having a `warning` message for the module `mingw` that was not found. For the UnusedInputError I searched online without finding anything useful and clear enough, so I started with the `warning`.

Comment: @Seintian I see no references to MinGW in OP. MinGW is a Windows port of GNU GCC - only relevant to Windows users.

Comment: @merv indeed the problem was the SMC sampler. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue in PyMC3. This appears to be something wrong with the SMC sampler when combined with multiprocessing. Changing to `parallel=False` will get the SMC sampler working. Changing to NUTS or Metropolis sampling will also work fine.

Please file a bug report on [the PyMC repository](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc). However, you may also want to try upgrading to PyMC v4 first.